# How to Convert Qcolor value to hex value?

Tags: qt, pyqt, hex

I have implemented a QColor dialog box which opens on certain condition.  To get the selected color after final selection I use the method `selectedColor()` which returns the value in QColor. When I print that value, it's like this:

```
<PyQt4.QtGui.QColor object at 0x01DD7880>
```

I want color value in hex value like this: `#DFDFDF` (for grey). If it's not hex, correct me.

Is there any function to convert that?

Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You need to print `selectedColor().name()` to print the actual color value in hex.  See the [QColor Documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qcolor.html#name)

Comment: Thank u very much Jason . ( i didn't read the docs deep enough )

Comment: this answer does not satisfy alpha option. It results like #RRGGBB but not alpha

Comment: The links is broken now

Comment: @ufukgun This one does (since Qt 5.2): https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcolor.html#name-1

Answer (score 3):

To amplify a bit, maybe confuse, maybe clarify... (For Python newbies)

```
color = QColorDialog.getColor(pWidget.textBackgroundColor(), pWidget, 'Get Text Highlighting Color')
```

The above will return a `QColor` using the `QColorDialog`, for those of us who don't want to be stuck with named colors like 'Blue', 'red', green etc.

```
fg = color.name()
```

In this case I am converting the `QColor` to a string HEX for use in a style sheet.

```
Widget.setStyleSheet('background-color: ' + bg + ';color: ' + fg)
```

This is how such a converted value can be used in a style sheet.

Note how to concatenate more than one stylesheet attribute. Also, side note, sometimes changing one attribute cancels previous changes to others.

Comment: Note: QColorDialog.getColor will fail if the attribute, in this case pWidget.testBackGroundColor, doesn't exist in the widget. You can use any other exisiting widget's color attribute.